# invoking a method from Server-side Java code to an IOS APP and receiving its synchronous response

Tags: java, ios, synchronous

I have a use case to invoke a method in my IOS mobile-app from my Server-side Java code hosted in Cloud, and then get a response from app. This use case is to ping the mobile and get its current location value(latitude & longitude). I need to make a synchronous call from server-side Java to IOS mobile APP. (I assume user has already accepted to share location 'Always' through my app).
Can you please advise an approach, or any link, I could refer to accomplish this use case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  guess I could use google-firebase from my Java code to invoke Push notification onto Mobile-APP and silently, without letting user know something happening inside APP, fetch that user's current location; though the App would remain closed.